# onClick event not firing correctly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, deployment

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 and C#. I am attempting to do some validation on the client side before the data is submitted.

Here is the javascript:

```
 function Validate() 
      {
        alert('Validating');
      // validation occurs...
      //...etc
       }
```

Here is my asp control:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="button" OnClientClick= "return Validate();" OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" Enabled="True" />
```

finally here is the html that is rendered:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$masterMain$btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="return Validate();" id="masterMain_btnSubmit" class="button" />
```

Here is the kicker. The validation is working perfectly on my local machine through VS2010. However, after I move the code to DEV or UAT it the "Validate()" event will not fire. There is a lot of other javascript code which does work but for some reason this event does not fire properly. Anybody have a clue as to why? I have been trying to understand why it works locally but not on the servers.

Comment: is the javascript code in the same page? or in a separated file?

Comment: I know it is not your question, but I'm curious to know why you're not taking advantage of the built-in .NET Validators?  (Otherwise, I would agree with where Mohamed is going - check to make sure external javascript files have been uploaded, and whether they are being cached)

Comment: Maybe there some problem in your deployment, missing file or include wrong url. Open the browser console and check if there's any error?

Comment: Is Validate() the actual method name in your production code or is that just for the purposes of this question?

Comment: If its a problem with Validate(), post the code for the validate method.  Your javascript is client side code, which runs on the client.  Therefore, when your code is being viewed through a browser, keep in mind that code is executing on the clients browser. So C:\myfile.text wouldn't be looking on your server when being viewed through a browser, it would be looking on the clients c drive.  You'll need some server side script like asp.net or jquery to do that.

Comment: You're probably referencing a javascript script file that is either not existent or not working on your other servers.  I bet your javascript is throwing an error and just not doing anything.